# pivot with visual basic 6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

how to code make if selected date 
from 2017-10-01 - 2017-10-06 (there are 5 day +1 = 6)
when click push button idaily added from idaily1 idaily2 idaily3 idaily4 idaily5 idaily6

[image]

```
    Option Explicit

Dim iDaily As Integer

Dim vSubTotal As Double
Public sQuery As String
Public pConnection As New ADODB.Connection

Dim rs As New Recordset
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

Private Sub openDB()
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSpi;persist security Info=false;Initial Catalog=test"

End Sub
Private Sub PushButton1_Click()
OseTextBox1.Text = DateTimePicker2.Value - DateTimePicker1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub PushButton2_Click()
FlatEdit1.Text = OseDateEnd.Value - OseDateStart
FlatEdit1.Text = FlatEdit1.Text + 1
iDaily = FlatEdit1.Text
lblLabel1.Caption = iDaily

Call openDB

rs.Open "select * from (select distinct id,item,whouse,st from testdrive )src pivot ( sum(st) for whouse in ([A],[B],[C],[iDaily1],[iDaily2],[iDaily3],[iDaily4],[iDaily5],[iDaily6]) ) piv ", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Set ReportControl.DataManager.DataSource = rs
ReportControl.DataManager.DataBind
'Set other ReportControl options
ReportControl.PaintManager.VerticalGridStyle = xtpGridSolid
ReportControl.PaintManager.HorizontalGridStyle = xtpGridSolid
ReportControl.AllowEdit = False
ReportControl.FocusSubItems = False
ReportControl.AllowColumnRemove = False
ReportControl.PaintManager.FixedRowHeight = False
ReportControl.AllowColumnSort = False
ReportControl.FreezeColumnsCount = 3
```

or make store procedure in sql server

Comment: Your topic is titled VB6, but you tagged this in VBA. Which is it?

Comment: im sorrry if i wrong place tagged sir, im still newbi